# put an html (scripted) menu in a separate file

Tags: jquery, html, menu

I have a menu that I've created using jquery that "pops-up" on certain button mouse-overs.

it has a LOT of options and sub-menu options and I'd like to put it into a separate file so that it only needs to be downloaded once and all of the html markup and text doesn't need to be re-downloaded every time a user hits a sub page on my site.

I was toying with the idea of using the jquery template engine but couldn't quite wrap my head around the best way to work that.  This isn't a template after all, but a static menu.

I'm pretty sure I can't put it in a JS file because it's not script per se, it's actual html markup (mostly tables).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not really sure what you mean but what I tend to do is include the html for all "pop-ups" in the original page markup and simply toggle `display` to `none` or `block` with whatever JQuery event you want, such as

```
$("button#popupbtn").click(function(){$("#hiddencontent").css("display", "block")});
```

This way you dont have to download the markup every time as you would if you were using Ajax and you get the SEO benefits of whatever is in the extra markup too.

If you did choose to use Ajax you could also prevent repeated downloading by caching the results (basically saving a local copy to reuse) after they have been downloaded, but this wouldn't really be necessary because the 1st method is easier and better for SEO

Comment: thanks for the reply tules.  What you suggest (display or hide) is what I'm currently actually doing and what I was hoping to avoid because it's makes my file size a LOT bigger having the entire menu on the page hidden.  This is why I want to put it off in another file that just needs to be downloaded once by the client so each sub-page can still use the menu that's already on the client.  Ajax isn't a good option because the menu needs to to be shown instantly when the button is moused over.  Does that make more sense now?

Comment: ah yes, then I would definitely try server side includes, they are commonly used for exactly this kind of thing: headers, menus, footers..
you can build entire page templates like this

Comment: SSI is also sometimes referred to as SHTML http://www.kennesaw.edu/webmaster/whatis/shtml.html

Comment: doesn't a server side include simply grab the html on the server and then send it down to the client as part of the page request?  I"m pretty sure they do and if that's the case, it wont' solve my problem as I'm trying to avoid having to send a 50k file down for each page load.

Comment: yeah ur right, I dont think there is a common way to cache html elements. You could cache the Ajax result but of course when the new page loads the cache will be lost, You can cache html files of course but as you said SSIs are constructed on the server. Perhaps you could include the menu in a .js file and have the JS insert the html on page load. Of course the JS file is cached so your essentially smuggling HTML inside it. I've often wondered myself why common page elements cant be cached but I guess the idea was that it's better to only have 1 http request than be able to cache

Comment: yeah, it definitely seems that the only way to do this would be to include the menu as a string in a javascript file which would then be automatically cached as disused here 


http://www.techrepublic.com/article/using-client-side-includes-instead-of-server-side-includes/5172019

I'm surprised there isn't a more common and simple method of doing client side includes myself!

Comment: ya that is what I was referring to in my OP.  I guess I could just script it as one big long nasty string in JS :/  Thanks for the ideas....

Comment: yeah look's like u will have to, why we are using hacks for client side includes in this age I dont know! I guess maybe HTML segments are rarely big enough to justify caching. Great question by the way!

Answer (score 0):

This may be too much of a roundabout, but having your html pages set to an XHTML doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

and using a php file extension ("index.php" instead of "index.html") instead you would then be able to use

```
<?php include("scriptedmenufile.php"); ?>
```

in place of the long menu code. Then, inside "scriptedmenufile.php" you will place the html code for your menu.

Comment: yeah php includes is similar, are they cached?

Comment: As is, nope.Until reading the comments off the accepted answer I too was focusing more on the SSI rather than cache.

Answer (score 0):

I would add this into a hidden div on the bottom of your page. Then when you want it to "pop up" I would use jquery ui dialog http://jqueryui.it/demos/dialog on that hidden div to pop it up in a dialog.

If you want it in a separate file you could use a server-side template and render it into the bottom of your main html page hidden

Answer (score 0):

So in conclusion this would be the only way to cache the menu individually (or any individual html elements) but bear in mind this would generate an extra http request the first time a user arrives at your site which may not be worth the 50k you're saving versus using serer side includes or `php include()`

```
$(function(){
    $("#menuholder").html("all the menu markup goes in here");
}) <!-- inside menu.js


<script src="menu.js"></script>


<div id="menuholder"></div>
```